# excel =sumif if cell contains a *

Tags: excel-formula

I need a little help with this function

=SUMIF(A5:A34;"<>*";D5:D34)+SUMIF(A37:A66;"<>*"; D37:D66)

this is my code. it sums the cell if it has annything other than a * in it. The problem is, that some cell have spaces in them and the code counts spaces as asterisks so if in a cell there is nothing but a space the code skips it (it should be counted) but if there is a space and a number it works ok.

Anny ideas ?

Thanks !

Comment: consider cleaning your data first with the `TRIM()` function. It will make things a lot easier for you

Comment: i dont think trim is the way to go here ... as the table is supposed to be dynamic... i just need this code to work even if there is space instead of blank cell

Comment: ok i got it .... figured out the trim function :) it does the job so thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that doesn't require trimming, although I would generally say cleaning data before using it is the best way to go:

using the following formula as set up below removes the blank spaces before summing. Put this formula in cell **E2** and drag down

```
{=SUM(IF(SUBSTITUTE($A$2:$A$7," ","")=D2,$B$2:$B$7,0))}
```

Leave out the curly braces and enter the function with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

Comment: the problem with the above code is that it does not do that dynamically , i have collumn A that hase * or nothing in them, collumn D has numbers ... below the table i have one cell that sums up all numbers that do not have anny * in front of them but the code i posted in my question doesnt look for "*" but for anny symbol , is there a way to limit the code to only look if there is no * then sum if there is * in the cell then dont sum

Answer (score 1):

Could you simple subtract the sum of all those rows where there is a space imitating an asterix.

```
=SUMIF(A5:A34,"<>",D5:D34)-SUMIF(A5:A34," ",D5:D34)+SUMIF(A37:A66,"<>",D37:D66)-SUMIF(A37:A66," ",D37:D66)
```